# MongoDB change streams lead to COLLSCAN with getMore

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, changestream

I've been recently using the Change Stream framework in pymongo to update dynamically a collection.

My pipeline is quite simple and is the following :

```
pipeline = [
            {"$match":
                {"$and":
                 [{"updateDescription.updatedFields.updated_data":
                  {"$exists": True}},
                  {"operationType": "update"}]
                 }
             }
        ]
```

It is used in the following code :

```
with collection.watch(pipeline) as stream:
    for insert_change in stream:
        '''DO SOMETHING'''
        resume_token = insert_change['_id']
```

This update happens quite often.

I'm monitoring the COLLSCANS of my db and I've realized that the getMore of the cursor induced by the watch method is performing a collscan each time it is called. Sometime it is a quite small collscan with a hundred of docsExamined but sometimes it inspects way more.

I could not find a way to build an index to eliminate this collscan. I'm thinking that I missed something.
Should I pass parameters to the cursor ? Should I build an index somewhere ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Try creating a [partialIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial) on presence of `updateDescription.updatedFields.updated_data` in documents of the collection  and share if that improves the query.

Comment: Thanks for your help Oluwafemi! I've created an index with the following command :
```self._collection.create_index([('updateDescription.updatedFields.updated_data', 1)], partialFilterExpression = {"updateDescription.updatedFields.updated_data": {"$exists": True}})```
However, I still observe a collscan on my collection when I do a test by modifying the ```updated_data``` of 10 000 documents.
Just for my general comprehension, I don't really get where ```updateDescription.updatedFields.updated_data``` is stored ? In my collection ? In the oplog ?

Comment: Good question. My original comment was misleading about the field for which to create the `partialIndex`. The field to create the index on should be `updated_data`.  [`updateDescription.updatedFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/index.html#update-event) is a document describing which fields are updated or removed. Documents in your watched collection may have `updated_data` field. Remove the index you created. Create on `updated_data` field, the filter expression should be `{"updated_data": {"$exists": True}}`.

Comment: Thanks for you explications !
I added a partial index on updated_data but it did not improve the query, I still have a collscan when I run my test of 10 000 updates.. Do you have any other lead ?

Comment: No worries. I don't have other leads for that.

Comment: @TitouanPoisson did you find out how to avoid collscans?

Comment: Im finding the same issue, any help is appreicated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/change-streams-production-recommendations/#indexes-and-performance), we cannot avoid the COLLSCAN on oplog collection.

So, in my opinion, in order to reduce the performance impact, `watch` should be run on the secondary instead of the primary.